# How find the disk sector size of a drive that's on a UNC-path

Tags: winapi

I've got the following code to get the drive sector size of a local or mapped drive:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "xhandle.h"
#include "DiskSectorSize.h"

DiskSectorSize getDiskSectorSize( char const *filename )
{
    using namespace std;
    DWORD dwFfnLength;
    if( (dwFfnLength = GetFullPathNameA( filename, 0, nullptr, nullptr )) == 0 )
        throw system_error( error_code( (int)GetLastError(), system_category() ),
                           (stringstream() << "can't get full path for path \"" << filename << "\"").str().c_str() );
    string fullFileName( (size_t)dwFfnLength, 0 );
    if( GetFullPathNameA( filename, dwFfnLength, &fullFileName[0], nullptr ) == 0 )
        throw system_error( error_code( (int)GetLastError(), system_category() ),
                           (stringstream() << "can't get full path for path" << filename).str().c_str() );
    if( dwFfnLength < 2 || toupper( fullFileName[0] ) < 'A' || toupper( fullFileName[0] ) > 'Z' || fullFileName[1] != ':' )
        throw exception( "no drive letter in absolute path" );
    string logicalDrive = "\\\\.\\  ";
    logicalDrive.replace( logicalDrive.begin() + 4, logicalDrive.begin() + 6, fullFileName.begin(), fullFileName.begin() + 2 );
    XHANDLE xhDevice( CreateFileA( logicalDrive.c_str(), 0, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL ), true,
                      "can't create device handle for disk" );
    DWORD                  dwOutSize;
    STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY spq;
    memset( &spq, 0, sizeof spq);
    spq.PropertyId = StorageAccessAlignmentProperty;
    spq.QueryType  = PropertyStandardQuery;
    STORAGE_ACCESS_ALIGNMENT_DESCRIPTOR saad;
    memset( &saad, 0, sizeof saad );
    if( !DeviceIoControl( xhDevice, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, &spq, sizeof spq, &saad, sizeof saad, &dwOutSize, NULL ) ||
        dwOutSize != sizeof saad )
        throw system_error( error_code( (int)GetLastError(), system_category() ),
                           (stringstream() << "can't detemine disk sector size for device" << fullFileName).str().c_str() );
    DiskSectorSize dss;
    dss.dwPhysical = saad.BytesPerPhysicalSector;
    dss.dwLogical  = saad.BytesPerLogicalSector;
    return dss;
}
```

But I can't get the disk sector size of a UNC-file with at. When I wrote the above code I also found a way to do that. But today I can't remember it exactly.

Comment: You could try to get the [`Win32_MappedLogicalDisk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-mappedlogicaldisk) for the mapped drive, and get all available members contained in the class.

Comment: So the real question is how to find the volume given a UNC path?

Comment: I want to get the disk sector size without a mapped logical disk, just witth the UNC-path @DrakeWu-MSFT / IInspectable.

Comment: I suppose you could try [GetVolumePathNameW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumepathnamew) followed by [GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPointW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumenameforvolumemountpointw) to get the volume's [GUID path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-volume).